# Customize dashed lines matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am comparing two plots, to differentate them I made one as solid and other as dashed. However I could see the difference, but it is not clear.
[image]

Is there a way to customize dashed graphs only so I could see the difference clearly?
I tried dashes(5,5) in the plot but it is applying to solid line as well.

EDIT: Here is the part of my code

```
def plot(self):
        # if self.image_count == 2:
        #     self.image_count = 0
        print("plot")
        self.counter=0
        if self.widget:
            self.widget.destroy()
        if self.toolbar:
            self.toolbar.destroy()
        fig = plt.figure()
        marker_list = ['-','--','-.',':']
        plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

        #setting x and y label of graph
        plot1.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
        
        # plot1.set_ylabel('Y - axis')

        #creating frame for plotting graph
        graph_frame = Frame(self.window)
        graph_frame.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.98, relheight=0.88)

        cs = self.list.curselection()
        for index in cs:
            f_name = self.list.get(index).split(":")[0]
            c_name = self.list.get(index).split(":")[1]
            x = self.cev_files[f_name]['Atd[0].Time'].tolist()
            y = self.cev_files[f_name][c_name].tolist()
            plot1.plot(x, y, linestyle=marker_list[self.counter],linewidth=1, label=c_name)#linewidth=1, markersize=12,
            plot1.set_ylabel(c_name)
            self.counter +=1
            if self.counter==3:
                self.counter=0
            # handles, labels = plot1.get_legend_handles_labels()
            # lgd = plot1.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 0.9))
            # fig.tight_layout()
            # self.image_count +=1
        #always place on upper right
        plot1.legend(loc="upper right")
        
        # plot1.legend(loc='best')
        # plot1.grid(linestyle ='--',linewidth=0.4)
        #place on best position
        #plot1.legend()
        if self.flag==True:
            img_name = str(time.time())+'.png'
            fig.savefig(img_name,  bbox_inches='tight')
            self.images.append(img_name)
        # creating the Tkinter canvas
        # containing the Matplotlib figure
        
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,
                                   master=graph_frame)
        canvas.draw()
```

PS: I am restricted to use this colors only.

Comment: Did you try the various line styles available in matplotlib? Show your code, it's hard to see what you tried without any code.

Comment: Give us your code, this does not look right. Check out this: https://matplotlib.org/3.0.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html

Comment: See this.[https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_demo_dash_control.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_demo_dash_control.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line styles are always better when you want to differ between plots. You can use any other style (not just dashed) to have more clear and different plots.
for styles check [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html).

According to my experience, increasing the size of matplotlib figures will highlight little features of the plot(line styling etc). you can try increasing the size of the plot.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
```